# PHP regex, replace every placeholder into SQL query

Tags: php, sql, regex, binding, placeholder

I'm trying to bind manually vars into SQL queries using PHP regex:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = '.'\''.mysql_real_escape_string(":bar \' :bar ' :bar ' :bar \' :bar").'\''.' OR foo = :foo AND fooo = :foo_o AND bar = :bar';
$binding = array(
    ':foo_o' => 'good',
    ':foo' => 'nice',
    'bar' => 'owned'
);
echo preg_replace_callback("/:\\w+(?![^']*'(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)/u", function($match) use($binding) {
    if(isset($binding[ltrim($match[0], ':')])) {
        return $binding[ltrim($match[0], ':')];
    } else if(isset($binding[$match[0]])) {
        return $binding[$match[0]];
    } else {
        return $match[0];
    }
},  $query);
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = ':bar \\\' owned \' :bar \' owned \\\' :bar' OR foo = nice AND fooo = good AND bar = owned
```

As you can see, two placeholders inside quotes are escaped but shouldn't be.

---

I also tried using the regex from here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5610067/4965547 ) that I already used to split multi queries and that worked very well for that, but not for binding:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('%:\\w+((?=\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\'|"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"|/*[^*]*\*+([^*/][^*]*\*+)*/|\#.*|--.*|[^"\'#])+(?:\\w|$))%xu', function($match) use($binding) {
    if(isset($binding[ltrim($match[0], ':')])) {
        return $binding[ltrim($match[0], ':')];
    } else if(isset($binding[$match[0]])) {
        return $binding[$match[0]];
    } else {
        return $match[0];
    }
},  $query);
```

In this case every placeholder is replaced, even between quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = 'owned \\\' owned \' owned \' owned \\\' owned' OR foo = nice AND fooo = good AND bar = owned
```

---

Any regex pro that can help me fixing one of the two expressions ? Thanks in advance.

---

**PS**: Yes I know I should use PDO, but I want to create a non-PDO adapter to use within mysql PHP extension, and yeah, I also know that this extension will be removed. Also I want not to use PHP script as more as possible, I really want to do it using regex.

---

**Edit 06/05/2015**: I finally understand how the complex regex works, and find a solution. So I post it here in case someone may need it or be interested.

*Binding with named placeholders:*

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = \''.mysql_real_escape_string(":bar \' :bar ' :bar ' :bar \' :bar").'\' OR b = \''.mysql_real_escape_string(':bar \" :bar " :bar " :bar \" :bar').'\' OR foo = :foo  AND fooo = :foo_o AND bar = :bar';
$binding = array(
    ':foo_o' => 'good',
    ':foo' => 'nice',
    ':bar' => 'owned'
);
echo preg_replace_callback('%(:\w+)\W*|(?:\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\'|"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"|/*[^*]*\*+([^*/][^*]*\*+)*/|\#.*|--.*|[^"\':#])+%u', function($match) use($binding) {
    if(isset($match[1]) && isset($binding[$match[1]])) {
        return str_replace($match[1], $binding[$match[1]], $match[0]);
    } else {
        return $match[0];
    }
},  $query);
```

*Same with question mark placeholders:*

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = '.'\''.mysql_real_escape_string("? \' ? ' ? ' ? \' ?").'\''.' OR '.'\''.mysql_real_escape_string('? \" ? " ? " ? \" ?').'\''.' OR foo = ? AND fooo = ? AND bar = ?';
$binding = array(
    1 => '*1',
    2 => '2*?',
    3 => 'lol',
    4 => 'none'
);
$count = 0;
echo preg_replace_callback('%\?|(?:\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\'|"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"|/*[^*]*\*+([^*/][^*]*\*+)*/|\#.*|--.*|[^"\'?#])+%u', function($match) use($binding, &$count) {
    if($match[0] == '?' && isset($binding[++$count])) {
        return $binding[$count];
    } else {
        return $match[0];
    }
},  $query, -1, $count);
```

*Good results:*

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = ':bar \\\' :bar \' :bar \' :bar \\\' :bar' OR b = ':bar \\\" :bar \" :bar \" :bar \\\" :bar' OR foo = :foo AND fooo = :foo_o AND bar = :bar
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = ':bar \\\' :bar \' :bar \' :bar \\\' :bar' OR b = ':bar \\\" :bar \" :bar \" :bar \\\" :bar' OR foo = nice AND fooo = good AND bar = owned

SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = '? \\\' ? \' ? \' ? \\\' ?' OR '? \\\" ? \" ? \" ? \\\" ?' OR foo = ? AND fooo = ? AND bar = ?
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = '? \\\' ? \' ? \' ? \\\' ?' OR '? \\\" ? \" ? \" ? \\\" ?' OR foo = *1 AND fooo = 2*? AND bar = lol
```

Comment: instead of trying to emulate PDO, why not use sprintf, or use easier to replace tokens such as `:myvariable:`. What is the advantage to your method over PDO? Programming is about solving problems, not creating them.

Comment: well this looks barking mad - carry on

Comment: You spent so much time wondering if you could that you didn't stop to think if you should.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Oh My, Don't Do This!**

Comment: @Augwa I did first, but it doesn't taking care about placeholders between quotes, and this is my real issue.